# Amazon Selling Partner API - manage FBM returns

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Using the api, I want to authorize the customer's return and provide him with a pre-paid postage label.

I was looking at the amazon selling partner api documentation, but I can't find anything that would allow me to manage returns.
Currently, using the "Reports API", I am downloading a list of returns, but I don't know how to authorize them using the api.